# Why is it "study the [instrument]" instead of "study playing the [instrument]"?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

Musicians often say things like "I study the violin", but "I majored in violin *performance*". It seems to me that it should be "I study violin performance" to both match with the thing actually being studied (violin *performance*; whenever someone talks about studying the violin I picture a person with a lab coat carefully dissecting a violin with magnifying glass and tweezers)

Someone might say "I study soccer", with the intent that they study the *playing* of soccer. This makes slightly more sense (though they could also mean the history of soccer), because there is very little that "soccer" can mean. It is not a physical object. However, saying "I study the violin" is a bit like saying "I study the soccer ball" when you mean that you study the sport. Can anyone explain the logic and/or history behind saying "I study the [instrument]" instead of "I study the performance of the [instrument]"?

Comment: the most likely answer is usually the most obvious one: because it has less words

Comment: **"However, saying "I study the violin" is a bit like saying "I study the soccer ball" when you mean that you study the sport."** The reason this analogy doesn't work out is that there aren't multiple instruments in the field of soccer: there's only one, a soccer ball. Meanwhile the field of music has multiple instruments, so it wouldn't make much sense to say "I study music" (unless you're a professor)

Comment: @V0ight I'm talking about saying "I study the [particular instrument, say, French horn]". I know saying "I study music" would be ambiguous, and probably most likely to be used for something like music theory, rather than an instrument

Comment: @Keepthesemind I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @cat40 ~ I know that's what you meant, I'm just trying to explain why this particular analogy doesn't work out. There's no other word like "study" that implies devoting a large period of your life to. "Practice" may imply short-term, while "play" may imply recreational. For sports like soccer, the analog to "study" is "compete".

Comment: @V0ight It seems to me that you are still misunderstanding the question. Will you please go back and read the question, particularly the title and first paragraph? As I said in the question, It seems to me that to "study the violin" means to devote your life to studying the instrument and how it works, rather than how to play it well and make music.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy

Comment: @cat40 ~ How specifically am I misunderstanding the question? You ask why we say "study this instrument" instead of "study the performance of this instrument". And my answer was "because it has less words". You made an analogy of an instrument to a soccer ball, which wasn't apt because you don't study an individual field in a sport (unless you do); you play or compete in it . Here is a definition of study according to dictionary.com: "20. to apply oneself to acquiring a knowledge of (a subject)"

Comment: @V0ight Your initial comment was valid. It would be nice if you'd post that as an answer. I'm sorry you don't like my analogy, but that's not what the question is about.

Comment: @cat40 ~ fair enough. I won't make it into an answer because it's too opinionated, but it likely is the reason for why this phrase has become colloquial

Comment: If you go to art school you might study sculpture or printing or graphic design. In dance class you study tap or ballet. A martial artist might study sword or bow. No need to include unnecessary words.

Answer (score 0):

To "study violin" would be to study all, or at least many aspects of violin.  How it works, how to play it, music for the violin, who has played it an how, how it is made, what modifications to the instrument can be made and how they will change it and its sound, and so forth.  To "study playing violin" is a more limited study.  This may not be what the writer intends by either statement, but it is easily how the differences of the two phrases can be read.